# Long running query vs processing in node application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bigdata

I have two collections. One collection is `band_profiles` with ~15,000 documents and a `player_profiles` collection with ~500,000 profiles. A player can be in a band and a band can hold up to 100 players. This information is purely informational, I haven't designed my database relational. The BandProfile document contains the necessary PlayerProfile information.

All information come from a thirdparty API, hence a PlayerProfile can be more updated than a BandProfile and vice versa. In order to find unknown bands I scan all PlayerProfiles and check for unknown Band IDs.

**My issue:**

Both collections are very large and I am able to find the unknowns id with an aggregate query which takes ~40-120s to run with the current dataset. I was worried because of the high CPU usage on my MongoDB and I considered trying options.

I thought I could process the data in my Express application. I used `find()` on both collections to fetch the whole collection data. Afterwards I processed the data in Express and I noticed that RAM rises by 4gb and CPU by 30% (1 debug instance on localhost).

**Hence I wonder:** What is the best way to process such large datasets? Is it fine to use long running MongoDB queries or should I rather process my data in Express for that purpose? Since this is a "BackgroundTask" it should not influence the performance of my website.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how much you care about the freshness of those large data set.

**1. Less fresh data approach**

You can make copy set of mongoDB and process the long aggregate query there.

**2. Freshier data approach (varies depends on CPU power / code efficiency)**

You can fetch data set with non-aggregate query and do those calculation in Node.js, JavaScript.

Comment: Well all I care about here is performance / resources. I noticed that the node application will use a lot of memory and CPU when I process data there. I assume because it would maintain the whole collections I've selected with mongoose. MongoDB would also use a lot CPU but I am also don't know about the pros and cons of processing it in MongoDB vs Node application